# How to find a web element based upon it's tag name and attributes using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to log into my Instagram account using Selenium. For that, I need to fill in my username and password into the login form.

The username input bar has the tag `input` and the `name` equal to `username`. Is there a way to retrieve this input bar using only the `name` attribute and the tag name? I know I can use the XPath and the class name, but I want to do this using the `name` attribute only.

I tried the code below but got an error.

Code:

```
username = driver.find_element(by = By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = "input[name = 'username']")
print(username.get_attribute("class"))
```

Output:

```
File "d:\Personal\CS\Bots\Instabot\msg.py", line 17, in <module>
    username = driver.find_element(by = By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = "input[name = 'username']")
```

Edit:

I tried the class name and the XPath too but they don't work either

XPath:

```
username = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
print(username.get_attribute("class"))
```

Class:

```
username = driver.find_element(by = By.CSS_SELECTOR, value = 'input._2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP')
print(username.get_attribute("class"))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125384/instagram-login-script-with-selenium-not-being-able-to-execute-send-keystest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You saw it right. The ***Phone number, username, or email*** `<input>` field has the *`name`* set as ***username***.

```
<input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">
```

---

So to locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")
  ```

---

As the element is an ***interactive*** element ideally to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```